# Program about radical numbers: IndexError: list index out of range [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, math, error-handling

I am sure about that there aren't any mistakes in my class. I can't give all codes because the program is big. The program is about **radical numbers. Such as converting √8 to 2√2**. I am going to use this class in my main python file. Here are the **codes**:

```
def kokluyazdir(self,number):
    i = 1
    bolenler_listesi = []
    for i in range(i,number):
        if (number % i == 0):
            bolenler_listesi.append(i)
        i += 1
    
    kontroldegiskeni = 0
    yazdirilacak = "1√{}".format(number)

    while True:
        if (kontroldegiskeni + 1 > len(bolenler_listesi)):
            break
        
        kontroldegiskeni += 1
        y = number // bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni]
        abc = self.tamkaremi(y)

        if (abc.endswith("tam karedir.")):
            yazdirilacak = "{}√{}".format(self.neyleneyincarpimi,bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni])

    return yazdirilacak
hesaplamalar = Hesaplamalar()
print(hesaplamalar.kokluyazdir(8))
```

**Here is the error:**

```
y = number // bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(i,number):->number=8
    if (number % i == 0):
        bolenler_listesi.append(i)
    i += 1
```

After completion of the loop bolenler_listesi will be[1,2,4], len=3

```
kontroldegiskeni = 0
while True:
    if (kontroldegiskeni + 1 > len(bolenler_listesi)): 
        break
    
    kontroldegiskeni += 1
    y = number // bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni]
    abc = self.tamkaremi(y)
```

when the above loop runs iteration values will be as follows:

iteration 1: (0+1 >3)--->false -->kontrodegiskeni=0+1=1--> y=8 // bolenler_listesi[1]

iteration 2: (1+1 >3)--->false -->kontrodegiskeni=1+1=2--> y=8 // bolenler_listesi[2]

iteration 3: (2+1 >3)--->false -->kontrodegiskeni=2+1=3--> y=8 // bolenler_listesi[3]

// error will be thrown here as index out of range because bolenler_listesi=[1,2,4], len=3
but here , here it's trying to access element greater than len of list  bolenler_listesi[3] (index for values in list starts from 0)

Answer (score 1):

```py
        if (kontroldegiskeni + 1 > len(bolenler_listesi)):
            break
```

since you increment kontroldegiskeni after the check it might equal the Len of the array when accessing which would cause the error. Instead the check should be done after the increment or make the condition

```py
        if (kontroldegiskeni + 1 >= len(bolenler_listesi)):
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an if condition inside the while loop when the "kontroldegiskeni" variable becomes equal to the length of array "bolenler_listesi". I tested the code as a stand alone function and it works with no errors. I couldn't verify the correctness of the output as this function depends on other classes.

```
def kokluyazdir(self,number):
    i = 1
    bolenler_listesi = []
    for i in range(i,number):
        if (number % i == 0):
            bolenler_listesi.append(i)
        i += 1
    
    kontroldegiskeni = 0
    yazdirilacak = "1√{}".format(number)

    while True:
        if (kontroldegiskeni + 1 > len(bolenler_listesi)):
            break
        
        kontroldegiskeni += 1
        if(kontroldegiskeni<len(bolenler_listesi)):
            y = number // bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni]
        abc = self.tamkaremi(y)

        if (abc.endswith("tam karedir.")):
            yazdirilacak = "{}√{}".format(self.neyleneyincarpimi,bolenler_listesi[kontroldegiskeni])

    return yazdirilacak
hesaplamalar = Hesaplamalar()
print(hesaplamalar.kokluyazdir(8))
```

Comment: As @khalilw1 has suggested, instead of adding another if condition, you can change the break condition.